# Macro runs while debugging but not when event happens

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to create a tool that both acts on new emails while Outlook is open as well as on emails received while the Outlook application is closed.

This is what I have so far:
-One sub that creates a note item upon quitting the app.
-One sub that filters emails in the inbox by the their received time.

The second sub is working when I debug (but also infinitely loops and reprocesses the new emails over and over), but does not work (as in does not take any action on the new emails) when I launch the application, expecting the startup event to trigger the sub.

Microsoft Outlook Objects/"ThisOutlookSession"):

```
Option Explicit

Private StartupTrigger As SaveAttachment1
Private ShutdownTrigger As Class2

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    
    Set StartupTrigger = New SaveAttachment1
    
    StartupTrigger.SaveAttachment1_Initialize
    StartupTrigger.Process_New_Items
    
End Sub

Private Sub Application_Quit()
    
    Set ShutdownTrigger = New Class2
    
    ShutdownTrigger.ExitApp
    
End Sub
```

Class Modules:

Class2

```
 Public Sub ExitApp()
 
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olNoteIt As Outlook.NoteItem
    Dim myFol As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myFilter As String
    Dim i As Object
    
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myFol = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderNotes) '.Folders("Attachment Filters")
    
    myFilter = "[Subject] = 'App Close Time'"
    
    For Each i In myFol.Items.Restrict(myFilter)
        
        i.Delete
        
    Next i
    
    Set olNoteIt = olApp.CreateItem(olNoteItem)
    
    With olNoteIt
        .Body = "App Close Time"
        '.Move myFol
    End With
    
    olNoteIt.Save
 End Sub
```

SaveAttachment1

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents olItems As Outlook.Items

Public Sub SaveAttachment1_Initialize()
    
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace

    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olItems = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("User ID (DMs) - Wells Fargo").Items

End Sub

Public Sub Process_New_Items()
    
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim filterString As String
    Dim olFol As Outlook.Folder
    Dim i As Object
    Dim olmi As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim cfilter As Object
    Dim my_olMail As MailItem
    Dim dmi As MailItem
    Dim utcdate As Date
    Dim filterfolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim SMTPAddress As String
    Dim olAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim olAttFilter As String
    Dim timeFol As Outlook.Folder
    Dim lastclose As String
    Dim timeFilter As String
    
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set filterfolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).Folders("FilterContacts")
    
    Set dmi = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set timeFol = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderNotes)
    
    timeFilter = "[Subject] = 'App Close Time'"
    
    For Each i In timeFol.Items.Restrict(timeFilter)
        
        lastclose = i.CreationTime
        
    Next i
    
    utcdate = dmi.PropertyAccessor.LocalTimeToUTC(lastclose)
    
    filterString = "@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"" >= '" & Format(utcdate, "dd mmm yyyy hh:mm") & "'"
    
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set olFol = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
        
        
            For Each i In olFol.Items.Restrict(filterString)
        
                If TypeName(i) = "MailItem" Then
                    If i.SenderEmailType = "EX" Then
                        SMTPAddress = i.Sender.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
                    Else
                        SMTPAddress = i.SenderEmailAddress
                    End If
                         For Each cfilter In filterfolder.Items
                            If SMTPAddress = cfilter.JobTitle Then
                                If InStr(1, LCase(i.Subject), cfilter.BusinessTelephoneNumber) <> 0 Then
                                    For Each olAtt In i.Attachments
                                            If InStr(1, LCase(olAtt.FileName), cfilter.HomeTelephoneNumber) <> 0 Then
                                                olAttFilter = fso.GetExtensionName(olAtt.FileName)
                                                    Select Case olAttFilter
                                                        Case cfilter.BusinessFaxNumber
                                                            olAtt.SaveAsFile cfilter.MobileTelephoneNumber & "\" & olAtt.FileName
                                                        Case Else
                                                    End Select
                                            Else: End If
                                    Next olAtt
                                Else: End If
                            Else: End If
                         Next cfilter
                End If
        
            Next i
        
End Sub
```

The "Process_New_Items()" sub is admittedly a mess, but essentially, it is referencing an Outlook contact item and uses the different fields of the contact item to filter the new emails, and then save the attachment if the email meets all the filter criteria.

Thanks!
Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> acts on new emails while Outlook is open as well as on emails received while the Outlook application is closed

First, to handle new emails I'd recommend using the [Application.NewMailEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.newmailex) event which is fired when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. Use the Entry ID represented by the `EntryIDCollection` argument to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`.

Another possible alternative is to using `ItemAdd` event on the Inbox folder.

You may find the following series of articles helpful:

- [Outlook NewMail event unleashed: the challenge (NewMail, NewMailEx, ItemAdd)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/03/outlook-newmail-event/)
- [Outlook NewMail event: solution options](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/24/outlook-newmail-solution-options/)
- [Outlook NewMail event and Extended MAPI: C# example](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/01/outlook-newmail-extended-mapi/)
- [Outlook NewMail unleashed: writing a working solution (C# example)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/10/outlook-newmail-custom-solution/)

Second, when Outlook is closed the OOM is useless.

Comment: Does OOM mean Object-oriented modeling? Any emails that are received while the application are batch processed upon Application startup. Since I create a new note item upon Application close, I can reference that creation time and handle all "new" emails (emails with a creation time after the note item's creation time which represents the last time the Application was open). 

For all other emails (ie: when the Application is open), I am using `ItemAdd`. I am not sure I need to make the folder reference dynamic as well. I want to be able to use `ItemAdd` on any Outlook folder.

Comment: I will look into the `Application.NewMailEx` event. It sounds preferential to `ItemAdd`. Do you have any article references on client rule processing? I would like to learn about that.

Comment: You can play with the `NewMailEx` event and see how rules are handled in Outlook.